# Переключение на landscape ориентацию в xCode

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

```
   Вобщем отключаю в проекте поддержку портретной ориентации (оставляю только две landscape). В сторибоард переключаю viewController на landscape ориентации, перетаскиваю на view самый обычный button.
   Запускаю симулятор, и мне телефон отображается в landscape ориентации, но всё содержимое отображается так как для портретной. Фото приложил.
   Самое интересное, что когда создаю новый проект и делаю точно так же, то всё отображается нормально. Но я хочу доделать старый проект, так как там уже написал достаточно кода.
http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130514/HeBT5x8m.png
http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130514/mIUPaUfo.png
http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130514/3UQeTrgi.png
```

Comment: Вобщем вот и думаю или это я с ума сошел, либо это apple корявый софт делает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вывод на основе скачанного и просмотренного проекта:

Действительно это поведение выглядит как баг: при всех необходимых параметрах установленных в Landscape соответствующее view не появляется горизонтально.

Я вижу два выхода:

1. Обновите проект: начните новый с нуля и скопируйте все соответствующие файлы.
2. Или используйте код ниже в соответствующем контроллере - я проверил, он решает проблему.

Мне был бы ближе второй вариант, так как я сторонник подхода, при котором все вопросы решаются кодом, а не через storyboards. А ещё лучше использовать сначала первый, а потом второй, подходы )))

См. документацию UIViewController:

```
Configuring the View Rotation Settings

    – shouldAutorotate
    – supportedInterfaceOrientations
    – preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
      interfaceOrientation  property
    + attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation
    – rotatingHeaderView
    – rotatingFooterView
    – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

То есть попробуйте добавить следующие методы в ваш ViewController, который связан с этим view:

```
#pragma mark
#pragma mark Interface orientations

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {    
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Возможно вам нужно будет немного изменить ваш код, исходя из ситуации.

И/или ещё гляньте в Xcode -> Ваш Storyboard -> Ваш ViewController -> Attributes inspector - Orientation - у вас же там стоит Landscape, да?

Comment: Я слегка подправил ответ.

Comment: ДА, там где Orientation стоит Landscape. А на счет кода, я одного понять не могу. Когда я создаю новый проект и делаю всё тоже самое, всё отлично отображается без всякого кода.

Comment: Ну что ж, zip вашего старого проекта в студию, чтобы не гадать лишнего - приложите ссылку на zip в конце своего вопроса.

Comment: Сейчас выложу. Самое главное, что я уже и сам класс от того контроллера что в storyboard отключил, и всё равно ни в какую

Comment: Ещё гляньте в Xcode: Targets -> Ваша target -> Summary -> Supported Interface Orientations.

Comment: Конечно там всё влючено. всё, выложил проект. Вы как скачаете, отпишите, чтобы я ссылку сразу удалил (чтобы лишние глаза не видели)